# How To drop Column Name From Pandas Data frame using regexp in Column Names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have to load excel file with few column to pandas data frame. In That Excel file some times data use come with column names "Unnamed 1" ,"Unnamed 2", "Unnamed 3" .
I want to delete all the columns where column names start with "Unnamed" .
How to do this ? Suppose my data frame name is df .

Comment: do you save CSV files through pandas?

Comment: Yes will save to CSV . Before that I want to drop the columns with column name starting with "Unnamed" .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use this with regex is:

```
df.drop(list(df.filter(regex = 'Unnamed')), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```